# Как определяется первый и второй план речи?

Tags: синтаксис, текст

В авторском варианте возможно различное толкование неоднородных и уточняющих обстоятельств места и времени, если сужение или расширение значения для уточняющих обстоятельств не является принципиальным. В этом случае они близки по значению и различаются ***по первому или второму планам речи***, причём обособление обстоятельств ***второго плана речи*** часто связано с их распространённостью:

1. А) Неоднородные (нераспространенные) обстоятельства: разные признаки, ***первый план речи:*** За рекой на горе лес зелёный стоит.
   Далеко на восток тянутся горные хребты.
   Летом в дождливую погоду здесь скучно.
2. Б) Уточняющие (обычно распространенные) обстоятельства: сужение значения,
   ***второй план речи:***
   За рекой, в розовеющем небе, ярко сверкала вечерняя звезда.
   Летом, вечерними зорями, на вершину кургана прилетает беркут.
   За рекой, на высокой горе, одиноко темнеет лес.

---

### В каком смысле здесь говорится о планах речи? Как их определять?

Answer (score 2):

**План речи** ― условное понятие. Вторым планом речи можно назвать **обособленные члены, которые находятся в середине предложения**. Они выделяются паузами, кроме того тон их произношения пониженный относительно основного тона предложения. Получается как бы пространственная структура **с двумя интонационными планами.** Интонация таких членов называется **вставочной.**

В приведенных примерах говорится о том, что неоднородные и уточняющие обстоятельства могут определяться **не только по смыслу, но и по структуре предложения.** Если второе обстоятельство распространенное, то его неудобно читать в составе простого предложения (тогда два обстоятельства нужно включать в одну фразу), **поэтому его обособляют (читают с паузами и с пониженным тоном)**, но при этом называют уточняющим.

Но истинная причина обособления в этом случае  ― это структура предложения.